# How Java compiler knows which function to use remove(int index) or remove(Object o)?

Tags: java, linked-list

I am making a Linked List of Integers

```
LinkedList<Integer> l1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
l1.add(1);
l1.add(2);
l1.add(3);
```

I want to remove 2nd entry i.e 2 from my list, So I used

```
l1.remove(2);
```

But actually, I found 3rd entry i.e 3 was removed. So `remove(int index)` was run by Java but I wanted `remove(Object o)` to run.

How to use `remove(Object o)` here ?

Comment: You're passing in `int` parameters... `int` is a primitive. You probably need to box it to an `Integer` object.

Comment: @Sotirios can you kindly post the link to actual question ???

Comment: It's already linked automatically, right at the top of your question, under the title.

Comment: got the answer. thanks man !!!